Dynamic and Unique MessageGroupId's for EventBridge Pipe FIFO SQS Target

I've setup a EventBridge Pipe target to be a FIFO SQS queue

The FIFO SQS has a Lambda Trigger that processes the messages in "batches of 1" (for my use-case, I need to process 1 at a time due to some tight constraints)

I've tweaked the SQS props (visibilityTimeout, delay etc) but have noticed that on multiple occasions, on SQS the messageSent (items being pushed into SQS by the pipe) is correct, but the lambda is not triggered and therefore messageReceive count is not the same as messageSent. Worse part is that the messages are not available in the queue anymore and not in DLQ as well. I've read that this is an issue with SQS queues with "low numbers" of events due to the distributed nature of AWS SQS.

BUT, one recommendation i've got is to make sure that each message generated from  the Pipe and sent to SQS should have a unique MessageGroupId. But EventBridge does not seem to allow for unique or dynamic values... you have to hardcode the same static value. (see below)



This was an issue 3 years ago as well, but i'm hoping this is fixed?

Does anyone know how to make the MessageGroupId in the Pipe dynamic (use a unique value/uuid from the source) / unique?
If still not possible, what architecture can I use with Pipe's to add another layer that can process and add unique MessageGroupId's before sending to the FIFO SQS?

Thanks very much!

I have a similar issue which is caused by the eventbridge pipe wrapping the original message in another "body".

You can use JSONPath to dynamically set a message group ID using an element of your payload. Here's some information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-event-target.html#pipes-targets-dynamic-parms
I'm concerned about messages being dropped... that REALLY doesn't seem right. Could you please ask AWS support to take a look? DM me if you don't have access to the support team and we'll tackle it together.

I believe JSONPath can only be used to update "body" before sending to target, but not the message group ID of the SQS message? (as in the console as well, message group ID is just an input box).
Yes, it was very weird and concerning to not see some SQS events in the queue or DLQ etc. Looking into it further

OK, I did some of my own testing and I am able to use JSONPath to specify a MessageGroupId and a MessageDeduplicationId. For the test, set up a Pipe from a standard SQS queue to a FIFO SQS queue. Then, under your target, use the following:
MessageGroupId: $.body.messageGroup
MessageDeduplicationId: $.body.messageDedupe
Feed in the following message to your origin SQS queue:
{
"somefield":"groovycats",
"messageGroup": "grouptester2",
"messageDedupe": "dedupetester2"
}
In the dest queue details, I see grouptester2 as the Message group ID and dedupertester2 as the dedupe ID.

Just type:
$.body.messageGroup
into the input box on the Pipes console in the Message group ID field. You need a dedupe ID as well in the "optional" box below to avoid "Bad Request" errors from SQS.
